# How to use frozen_inference_graph.pb file of tensorflow (GPU) at some other PC?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Working on TensorFlow object detection API, I trained faster RCNN model for ship recognition at my PC on tensorFlow (GPU) and generated  frozen_inference_graph.pb file. 
Now I want to use this model on my laptop which has tensorFlow(CPU).
How could I use this  frozen_inference_graph.pb file.
Is there any other way?
what files do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply run the detector, you need to follow the [guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/70b176a9193859a53354fbbdbdef8624932cd0d3/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)